# The swapping of two elements in a list doesn't work

Tags: python, sorting, swap

```
def sortingStoL(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for item in lst[i + 1:]:
            if item < lst[i]:
                print(item, lst[i])
            lst[i], item = item, lst[i]
            print(lst)
    return lst

a_list = [5, 4, 3, 2]
print(sortingStoL(a_list))
```

I am having difficulty figuring out how to fix this code.
I am trying to sort elements in `a_list` from small to large, but what I get is like this,

```
4 5
[4, 4, 3, 2]
3 4
[3, 4, 3, 2]
2 3
[2, 4, 3, 2]
3 4
[2, 3, 3, 2]
2 3
[2, 2, 3, 2]
2 3
[2, 2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2, 2]
```

it looks like the line

```
lst[i], item = item, lst[i]
```

has a problem, since it does not swap two elements correctly, but just overwrites bigger one with the small one.

Comment: you're swapping the items each time instead of in the < condition. Indent this line `lst[i], item = item, lst[i]` like the above print

Comment: Probably you need to track indices in the inner loop as well: `for y, item in enumerate(lst[i + 1:]):`.. Then you can swap both items. Now I think you only swap `item` into `lst[i]`.

Comment: you can also use `a_list.sort()` btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are swapping (modifying the contents of list) you need to use indices in inner loop as well.

```
def sortingStoL(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(i + 1,len(lst)):
            if lst[j] < lst[i]:
                print(lst[j], lst[i])
                lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]
            print(lst)
    return lst

a_list = [5, 4, 3, 2]
print(sortingStoL(a_list))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feed back. that worked! i realized that swapping lst[i], and item which is just a temporary thing in a for loop, doesnt swap becuase I dont have 'item' in the original list. thank  you